# SQL Alchemy selecting data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a group by + count with a weather stations table to answer the following questions:

## What are the most active stations? (i.e. what stations have the most rows)?

## List the stations and the counts in descending order

The table consists of the following values:
id INTEGER
station TEXT
date TEXT
prcp FLOAT
tobs FLOAT

This is my current formulation of the select statement:

```
sel = [Measurement.station, func.count(Measurement.id)]
count = session.query(*sel).all()

count
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, a GROUP BY clause needs to be applied to that query. This can be easily done in sqlalchemy: `count = session.query(*sel).group_by(Measurement.station).all()`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I would add an order by desc id count?

Comment: If you mean ordering by the station, you just need to add ```.order_by(Measurement.station.desc())``` before ```.all()```. You are aggregating by id, so you can't order by this column.